# FragmentManager children and findViewById NullPointer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I currently have a FragmentActivity named **PlayActivity**. PlayActivity contains 5 child Fragments. In the onStart() method of PlayActivity, I am trying to reference an ImageView inside of one of the child fragments using **findViewById(R.id.avatarView)**, however, it is coming up null.

Code in PlayActivity:

```
public void updateAvatar(Bitmap avatar)
{
    ImageView avatarViewer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatarView);
    avatarViewer.setImageBitmap(avatar);
}
```

XML of child fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".PlayerActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatarView"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:src="@drawable/energy_icon" />
```

Comment: Please post more relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly access elements of the fragment's view from your activity. Only the relevant fragment can access its own visual elements.

Create a public method in the fragment that would take a `Bitmap` parameter and set the bitmap to the proper `ImageView`. Then call this method from your activity and pass the bitmap to it.